# Why can't I rename files that are saved in a SharePoint Folder using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure why I get the below error message when running the below macro to rename excel files that are saved on a SharePoint Folder on my File Explorer. When I have used this macro in the past to rename files that were saved in my OneDrive folder, it worked like a charm. Does anyone know why the macro is failing and how to fix it?

[image: Macro + Error Message]

[image: Target Files]

I tried running a macro (See Macro + Error Message image) in order to change the names of specific files (See Target Files image). This macro has always worked when changing files saved to my OneDrive folder. I thought it would work with files saved in a SharePoint folder but that doesn't seem to be the case. Does anyone know why the macro is failing and how to fix it?

Comment: `target_folder` is a folder on your local drive which is synced to SharePoint?  I don't have any trouble renaming files in a synced folder using VBA.